# Deploying a contract with a "payable" constructor and including input parameters?

Tags: contract-development, web3js, balances, payable, constructor

There is a useful `Solidity` contract [HERE](https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2018/02/23/writing-a-simple-payment-channel/). However, there are **two** things at time of its deployment:

(1) The first thing is the `contract balance` since its `constructor` is `payable`. 
(2) And the second one is the `constructor's parameters value` (`(address **_recipient**, uint256 **duration**)`)

To deploy a contract I use `web3.js 1.0.0-beta.34`. Here is the steps I do to deploy this contract:

```
Web3 = require("web3")
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));

const bytecode = '0x1234 ....
const abi = ....

web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount('0x123...', 'password')

var thisContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, {
    from: '0x123...',
    gasPrice: '20000000000'
});

thisContract.deploy({ data: bytecode }).estimateGas(function(err, gas) { console.log(gas); });

thisContract.deploy({ data: bytecode }).send({
        from: '0x123...',
        gas: 5000000 ,
        gasPrice: '3000000000'
    },
    function(error, transactionHash) {
        console.log(error);
        console.log(transactionHash);
        console.log('function exec');
    }).then(function(newContractInstance) {
    console.log('Contract Instance:' + newContractInstance.options.address);
});
```

However, I do not know **where** in the above process I must determine `(1) the contract balance` (since its `constructor` is `payable`) and `(2) the constructor's parameters value` (i.e. `(address _recipient, uint256 duration)`) ?

Note: I guess first I have to deploy this contract using `remix` where I determine the `constructor's parameters values` and then use generated `bytecode` and `abi` by `remix` in the web3.js above code. However, I am not sure where can I use `value: web3.toWei(1/*contract balance*/, 'ether')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [the example](http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#id11):

```
const thisContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi);
thisContract.deploy({  
        data: bytecode,
        arguments: [ "0x2345...", 12000 ] <- Here you put your constructor arguments in order
    }).send({
       from: "0x1234...",
       gas: 5000000 ,
       gasPrice: '3000000000',
       value: 120 <- Here you put how many wei to send to the constructor
    },
    function(error, transactionHash) ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Just, I need to run JavaScript code to sign a payment by `signPayment ` function (Full code is [here](https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2018/02/23/writing-a-simple-payment-channel/)). So, I saved the JavaScript code in a `.js` file (You can see the content of this `.js` file [HERE](https://ibb.co/dSq0jy).) However, when I run this file by `node filename.js` I receive the `error message` that I uploaded the screen shot [HERE](https://ibb.co/hKb1rd). I do not know where I am going wrong. Thanks again.

Comment: You should probably open a full new question.

Comment: You have to replace `callback` with `function(err, something) {}`.

Comment: In fact, I asked another question here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/52584/signing-a-message-using-ethereumjs-abi Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. I did your comment in the code and uploaded the new version. (now i receive Invalid JSON RPC response) I also added two important notes at the end of my question : web3.js version 1.0 and running this JavaScript file in Terminal (Ubuntu) : node filename.js Thanks again. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/52584/signing-a-message-using-ethereumjs-abi