# (NEW UPDATE: I need to run "testrpc") Signing a message using "ethereumjs-abi"? (Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: "")

Tags: javascript, ethereumjs, signature, ecdsa

I am trying to sign a message using following JavaScript code (from [HERE](https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2018/02/23/writing-a-simple-payment-channel/))

```
function constructPaymentMessage(contractAddress, amount) {
  return ethereumjs.ABI.soliditySHA3(
    ["address", "uint256"],
    [contractAddress, amount],
  );
}

function signMessage(message, callback) {
  web3.personal.sign("0x" + message.toString("hex"), web3.eth.defaultAccount,
    callback);
}

// contractAddress is used to prevent cross-contract replay attacks.
// amount, in wei, specifies how much ether should be sent.
function signPayment(contractAddress, amount, callback) {
    var message = constructPaymentMessage(contractAddress, amount);
    signMessage(message, callback);
}
```

I have tried several approaches to run this code and get its output (signed payment), however, I could not run it successfully.

[HERE](https://ibb.co/dSq0jy) is the screen shot of the `.js` file I created and [HERE](https://ibb.co/hKb1rd) is the error message I receive when I run it by `node sign.js` . And when I remove callback from the code, I receive another error.

> **What is the correct approach to run this code to get its output (i.e. signed message) ?**

**UPDATE**: I modified the code as follows:

```
Web3 = require("web3")
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));

var ethereumjs = require('ethereumjs-abi')

web3.eth.defaultAccount = '0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c';


function constructPaymentMessage(contractAddress, amount) {
  return ethereumjs.soliditySHA3(
    ["address", "uint256"],
    [contractAddress, amount],
  );
}

function signMessage(message, callback) {
  //web3.eth.personal.sign("0x" + message.toString("hex"), web3.eth.defaultAccount, callback);

web3.eth.sign("0x" + message.toString("hex"),"0x135a7de83802408321b74c322f8558db1679ac20");

}

// contractAddress is used to prevent cross-contract replay attacks.
// amount, in wei, specifies how much ether should be sent.
function signPayment(contractAddress, amount, callback) {
    var message = constructPaymentMessage(contractAddress, amount);
    signMessage(message, callback);
}

signPayment('0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c', 1, function(err, something) {});
```

I need to run `testrpc` before running this code.
Now the error message is as follows:

> **"Error: Returned error: Error: cannot sign data; no private key"**

**And here is screen shot of the error message :**

[image]

**NOTE 1:** I am using web3.js version 1.0.

**NOTE 2:** I run this JavaScript file in Ubuntu Terminal: `node filename.js`.

**NOTE 3:** Since I use `web3.eth.personal.sign(dataToSign, address, password [, callback])` I do not need to use a password for this address ? > `web3.eth.personal.sign("0x" + message.toString("hex"), web3.eth.defaultAccount);`

**NOTE 4:** There is a similar problem here: [similar problem](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7796/invalid-json-rpc-response-in-browser-solidity) but in `remix`.

**NOTE 5:** And alternatively, is there any other approach to sign such a message instead of using `web3.js` and `ethereumjs-abi` ?

Comment: What is you replace with `0xCA35b7d915458EF540aDe6068dFe2F44E8fa733c`?

Comment: @Xavier Leprêtre B9lab, I used it as an example for contractAddress input parameter. to invoke signPayment function. Thanks.

Comment: @Xavier Leprêtre B9lab Maybe I have to remove '0x' from '0xCA35b7d915458EF540aDe6068dFe2F44E8fa733c', isn't it?

Comment: @Xavier Leprêtre B9lab Or maybe it's because of removing 'callback' from the code?  Thanks

Comment: The new error is because `web3.eth.defaultAccount` is `null`. Perhaps put in the actual address you intend to sign with (the account you've set up in the local Ethereum node).

Comment: Look carefully at the difference between `0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c` and `0xCA35b7d915458EF540aDe6068dFe2F44E8fa733c`. One has the `capitalization checksum` on, the other not. This is what your original error message was about.

Comment: @smarx @Xavier Leprêtre B9lab Thank you. I did your comments in the code and uploaded the new version. (now i receive `Invalid JSON RPC response`) I also added two `important notes` at the end of my question : `web3.js version 1.0` and `running this JavaScript file in Terminal (Ubuntu) : node filename.js` Thanks again.

Comment: Make sure the account you're using is one that exists in your Ethereum node (geth, Parity, ganache, or whatever). The error indicates that the node doesn't know the private key for that account.